# Can a gridview datasource be another gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can a gridview datasource be another gridview and how?

```
'table2 is a custom datatable

Dim myCustomGV As GridView = New GridView()
myCustomGV.DataSource = table2


'GridView1 is a control on the page
GridView1.DataSource = myCustomGV
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Are you trying this GridView1.DataSource = myCustomGV.DataSource ?

Comment: I think you need to do:  GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)myCustomGV.DataSource;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No a Grid view's data source should be an object which implemts IDataSource, and obviously GridView dose not implement that. So you cant and it dosent make sense either.

Here is a link to help you with
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.idatasource.aspx